# Prev/Next on field group horizontal tabs

Tags: 7, entities

I'm using entityform and Field group to create a multi-step form, using Horizontal tabs.

I'd like the Prev/Next buttons, that show when you use Multipage, to show when using horizontal tabs.  i.e tabs + Prev/Next

I'd like pointers on how to go about coding it myself (if it's not currently configurable) as I don't know where to start.

Comment: If your question is really "is this possible?" then the answer is just as simple: "yes". If you want it to be done, you need to post a feature request in project's issue queue or in the issue queue of the theme you are using. Unless you want to code it yourself - if so, show us what you have now. Either way, at the moment your question looks more like code request than a real question suitable for Q&A format.

Comment: I just need pointers on how to code it myself if it's not currently configurable.  I won't spend time coding up a solution if someone knows a good way to do this using a hook somewhere or an existing additional module.

Comment: Sorry, but this site is for questions and answers not for tutoring... That's why we have this in [help center](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic): *"Questions that are substantially about code, where the code is not shown, are possibly closed."*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, well before this is closed, I will post what I did in the hope it might help someone.

I added a #tab_back/#tab_next buttons to the form, and used a bit of jquery to handle the UI.

```
  var current_tab = 0;
  jQuery("#tab_back").hide();
  jQuery(".entitytype-tab_tool-form").find('input[type=submit]').hide();

  function click_tab(inc)  {

    newtab = current_tab + inc;
    if (newtab >= 0 && newtab <= 4 )  {
      jQuery('.horizontal-tab-button-'+newtab).find("a").click();
      current_tab = newtab;
      jQuery("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
    }
    return false;
  }

  jQuery("#tab_back").click(function () {
    click_tab(-1);
    return false;
  });

  jQuery("#tab_next").click(function () {
    click_tab(1);
    return false;
  });

  jQuery('.horizontal-tab-button-0').find("a").click(function () {
    current_tab = 0;
    jQuery("#tab_back").hide();
    jQuery("#tab_next").show();
    jQuery(".entitytype-tab_tool-form").find('input[type=submit]').hide();
  });

  jQuery('.horizontal-tab-button-1').find("a").click(function () {
    current_tab = 1;
    jQuery("#tab_back").show();
    jQuery("#tab_next").show();
    jQuery(".entitytype-tab_tool-form").find('input[type=submit]').hide();
  });

  jQuery('.horizontal-tab-button-2').find("a").click(function () {
    current_tab = 2;
    jQuery("#tab_back").show();
    jQuery("#tab_next").show();
    jQuery(".entitytype-tab_tool-form").find('input[type=submit]').hide();
  });

  jQuery('.horizontal-tab-button-3').find("a").click(function () {
    current_tab = 3;
    jQuery("#tab_back").show();
    jQuery("#tab_next").show();
    jQuery(".entitytype-tab_tool-form").find('input[type=submit]').hide();
  });

  jQuery('.horizontal-tab-button-4').find("a").click(function () {
    current_tab = 4;
    jQuery("#tab_back").show();
    jQuery("#tab_next").hide();
    jQuery(".entitytype-tab_tool-form").find('input[type=submit]').show();
  });
```

For what it's worth, I didn't really need tutoring, just help knowing which avenue to explore as it could have been done many different ways.  Anyway, hope this helps someone.  feel free to pick at my javascript... It's not my forte.